# jquery ajax success event handler not getting called

Tags: node.js, jquery, client-side

- Node.js (express) web server
- Request handler in web server

> ```
> app.get('/documents/ajax/:id.:format?', function(req, res) {
>    console.log ('Request Received');
>    var body = 'hello world';
>    res.writeHead(200, {
>     'Content-Length': body.length,
>     'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
>    });
>
> })
> ```

- ajax request from client side javascript

> ```
>   $.ajax({
>     url : "/documents/ajax/" + item,
>     success : function(msg) {
>       alert ("success" + msg);
>     },
>     error : function(request, status, error) {
>       alert("Error, returned: " + request);
>       alert("Error, returned: " + status);
>       alert("Error, returned: " + error);
>
>     }
>   });
> ```

- I am able to receive the request on server side and I send 4 requests

But my success event is not getting called in client side JS. Also, when I stop my web server, then I see my error handlers get called.

Please help.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: jQuery JavaScript Library v1.4.4

Comment: A proper URL would normally be `"/documents/ajax/" + item`, depending on what `item` is ?

Comment: My mistake: I had a slash there. I drafted the question before I realized that myself. So I still have the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you are not ending the response so the server never actually sends anything to the client. The server should respond with something like a file, a redirect, some text, etc. You need to finish the callback with a `res.end`, `res.send`, `res.sendfile`, `res.redirect`, `res.render`... See the [docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html).

Furthermore, with express you want to use `res.set` to set the http headers:

```
app.get('/documents/ajax/:id.:format?', function(req, res) {
   console.log ('Request Received');
   var body = 'hello world';
   res.set({'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
   res.send(body);
});
```

`200` is the default response code, so you don't need to specify that and the length will be computed for you. These things are often easier to debug from the command line via `curl`:

```
curl http://localhost:3000/documents/ajax/1
```

and

```
curl -I http://localhost:3000/documents/ajax/1
```

Comment: You can also finish the callback using res.end(...); as well.

Comment: In 2016, the syntax is different to set headers: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value

Answer (score 1):

I had to res.end in server request handler. After that I was able to generate success event in client side JS